# Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 8 (SQL Server) error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I get **Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  8 (SQL Server)** error while trying to access SQL Server 2005 from C++ code. Basically I am developing an ISAPI dll in Visual C++, from which I am making a SQL DB call to pick certain information based on few error conditions. Following is the code which I am using to open the DB connection:

```
CDatabase DBConnection;
DBConnection.OpenEx("Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.104.20.14;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes;", CDatabase::openReadOnly | CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);

CRecordset RecSet(&DBConnection);

RecSet.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly,_T("{CALL SP_CheckForInfo('" + URLtoCheck +"')}"));
```

Any idea what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 8 (SQL Server)

Is this the only error description you are getting? Usually there is more.

Did you have this problem before? Is this the first time you are trying to connect?

What part of code is causing this error?

Sytem error 8 means: ***Not enough storage is available to process this command.***

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for your response. When i checked the log, i can see "Out of memory" exception got caught before the "system error 8". So after reading your comment, i am guessing the issue here is  the code is unable to load the SQL Server driver since there is not enough storage available.